Webpack 5: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'probe-image-size' module
Here is the image of error
I am encountering an error while using Webpack 5 with the probe-image-size library in my project. The error message I get is:
ERROR in ./node_modules/probe-image-size/lib/common.js 3:16-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/jay/Desktop/Darshil/work/gpsatsys/GriffinWebpageSN/GriffinEventLoggerUI/frontend/node_modules/probe-image-size/lib'

It also mentions:
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

I have already tried adding stream-browserify to my project and updating the webpack.config.js file, but I still face the same error.
Here is what my webpack.config.js looks like:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const start = require('./src/index');

module.exports = {
    entry: start,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  // Output directory
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        fallback: {
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/")
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,  // Allows routing in SPA to work properly
        static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
    },
};


Could anyone suggest what I might be missing or doing wrong?
Additional Info:
Webpack version: ^5.92.1
Node version: 16.20.2
Operating System: Ubuntu
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
